# Cannot unhighlight unbutton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, highlighting

I have some problems with uibutton. I want a button to highlight when pressed but unhighlight when other buttons are pressed but I cannot get the previous button to unhighlight. Can anyone please advise?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)button2:(id)sender;
-(void) highlightButton: (UIButton *) button;
-(void) unhighlightButton: (UIButton *) button;
@end


@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize button1, button2;

-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{

    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
    [button2 performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:button2 afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(IBAction)button2:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
    [button1 performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:button1 afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(void) highlightButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button setHighlighted:YES];
}

-(void) unhighlightButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button setHighlighted:NO];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using properties, change these two lines in two ways:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:self.button2 afterDelay:0.0];
```

and

```
[self performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:self.button1 afterDelay:0.0];
```

1) properties should be referred to with "`self.`"

2) you're calling the method "`unhighlightButton:`" which lives in the view controller, hence you need to call it on "`self`" and not a "`button`".  "`button`" gets passed via the "`withObject:`" parameter.

Why are you using the "`performSelector`" methods, anyways?

You could rewrite one of the action methods to do:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    [sender setHighlighted: YES];
    if(sender == self.button1)
    {
       [self.button2 setHighlighted: NO];
    } else {
       [self.button1 setHighlighted: NO];
    }
}
```

and point both buttons to that one IBAction.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks but I've tried this line and it doesn't work. Should this line reside in the IBAction method or somewhere else? I thought if "self" in the IBAction method points to "sender", in which case points the pressed button (button1 or button2) so the other button is not referred to as "self"? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you set an Xcode breakpoint in your "`unhighlightButton:`" method, does it ever hit?

Comment: Yes it does. It gets hit.

Comment: check and make certain the button in "`unhighlightButton`" is not nil.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check that `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` connection are properly connected.

```
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:button2 afterDelay:0.0];
    }

    -(IBAction)button2:(id)sender
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:button1 afterDelay:0.0];
    }

    -(void) highlightButton:(UIButton *)button
    {
        [button setHighlighted:YES];
    }

    -(void) unhighlightButton:(UIButton *)button
    {
        [button setHighlighted:NO];
    }
```

Comment: I'm upvoting yours since it's so nice and concise.

Comment: I get a warning message "local declaration of button1 hides instance variable" and button1 does not turn to green. Is that ok?

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, I tried it but it doesn't highlight the buttons. Is there something I'm missing in my declaration?

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, pressedButton can't seem to highlight the button.

Comment: first tell me your exact requirement ... you can try this using setSelected

Comment: I'm trying to create a calendar and in calendar the dates get highlighted when you touch them and it will unhighlight when you touch another.

Comment: ok ,initially set selected and normal Image to your button then on button press use [btn setSelected:yes];

Comment: Just remove   [button1 per...]    with    [self per...]

Comment: and check IBOutlet connection

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, I tried 
[self performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:button2 afterDelay:0.0];     and
[self performSelector:@selector(unhighlightButton:) withObject:button1 afterDelay:0.0];

and it doesn't unhighlight the buttons.

Comment: your code working fine at my end.. First of all check that IBOutlet and IBAction connection are properly connecte

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, I connected my buttons via "Sent Events -> Touch Up Inside" . Is there another connection that I must make?

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, I want to let you know that I just managed to do it. Somehow the IBOutlets aren't appearing at the interface builder. I redo the app and typed uibutton declaration in stages. This allows me to link the buttons at the 'Outlets' before declaring IBAction methods. Thanks for the tip! Good night!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use selected property of UIButton :
For both button selector would be same "buttonTouched"

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {

     button1.selected = NO;
     button2.selected = NO;

     if (sender == button1) {
          button1.selected = YES;
     } else if (sender == button2) {
          button2.selected = YES;
     }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: but for both button you have to set different image for selected state.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below...

```
 -(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
 {

 button1.highlighted = YES;
  button2.highlighted = NO;
 }

 -(IBAction)button2:(id)sender
 {
  button2.highlighted = YES;
  button1.highlighted = NO;
 }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Hi Nirav, it doesn't work :( It doesn't get highlighted. I tried changing it to self.button1.highlighted and self.button2.highlighted but it still won't get highlighted.

Comment: Should I? I'm not using any custom button but the Round Rect Button.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Actually I tried this command and it worked:-

-(IBAction) button1: (id) sender
{[self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];}

-(void) highlightButton:(UIButton *)button
{button.highlighted = YES;}